# Given the civic number and postal code, how do find the full complete address in the google maps API?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, street-address

I'm in Canada and in the Google maps API, It seems there's no way to find the full complete address using only the civic number and postal code, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Google Maps API doesn't have the capability to search for an address using a civic number and a postal address, the closest API to this function is [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) as this can look up for a postal code. However, the Geocoding API is meant to geocode well-formatted address and not to assist a search for an address, if you wish to have a function that will assist your users to find an address, you may use the [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) as a workaround but this also doesn't support the search for civic address.

I would suggest that you file a Feature Request in the [Issue Tracker of Google Maps Platform](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309) in order for the engineers to review the feasibility of your request. This would also be a good request as the civic number are used in emergency situations as well.